# How to create advanced custom fields for backend content

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, content, custom-content

Is there a straightforward way to create custom fields for module-based content on WordPress?

Example:

1. User Creates page

   Creates Page content sections through forms

- Row 1: Column 1 - **Content A**  Column 2 **Content B**
- Row 2: Column 2 - **Full-width   Content A**
- Row 3  Column 3 - **Content A** Column 2 **Content B**

This is based on using Bootstrap as the CSS.

I want the user to be able to not create HTML code if not necessary and fill out predetermined sections of the website.

Any tutorials or videos would help out tremendously. All I find is creating custom taxonomies and custom theme templates.

Comment: Here's a decent start:  https://wpmudev.com/blog/creating-meta-boxes/  There are even meta box generating plugins. (The bootstrap CSS aspect of this is irrelevant.)
It is entirely possible to generate your own meta boxes for existing post types (page or post) or for your own custom post type so that you can record information from the user and then output that in the correct manner you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I ended up using Advanced custom fields.